# Will prefinished Maple flooring yellow with age?

Tags: hardwood-floor

I'm considering a prefinished "natural character" Maple floor (uv aluminum oxide).

The salesman said I don't need to worry about it yellowing over time but I wanted to ask you folks.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it will discolor over time.

I have prefinished maple flooring in my living room with an area rug on it. I also have one window that is single pane without low-e. The sun has shined in (direct light over about 12 years) and discolored the floor around the area rug. Now, I can’t move the rug or it will show the “discoloration”.

I’d be careful if there is direct sunlight.

Comment: I'm accustomed to discoloration but I'm used to it either darkening (like cherry) or blonding (like walnut) I'm specifically wondering if it gets yellow.

Comment: Mine darkened, but it probably maters which brand of stain is used.